# Codeigniter or_where condition not working well

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here is my mysql table (chatizin)

| Id | Sender | Receiver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 6 |
| 2 | 11 | 96 |
| 3 | 6 | 96 |
| 4 | 6 | 11 |

And Here is my php codes by using codeigniter 3

```
$UserId=11;
$Receiver=6;

$this->db->where(["Sender" => $UserId,"Receiver"=>$Receiver]);
$this->db->or_where(["Sender" => $Receiver,"Receiver"=>$UserId]);
$this->db->order_by("Id DESC");
$sohbetciler = $this->db->get("chatizin")->result();
```

What i am trying to do is getting below result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 4
            [Sender] => 6
            [Receiver] => 11
            
        )


    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Sender] => 11
            [Receiver] => 6
        )

)
```

But or_where condition not working as i want. instead it gave me below result. Why it takes Id=3 there is no condition to bring Receiver=96

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 4
            [Sender] => 6
            [Receiver] => 11

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 3
            [Sender] => 6
            [Receiver] => 96

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 1 
            [Sender] => 11
            [Receiver] => 6
           
        )

)
```

```
$this->db->or_where(["Sender" => $Receiver,"Receiver"=>$UserId]);
```

in or_where condition "Receiver"=>$UserId this part not working please help me

Comment: Which is it, `$UserId` or `$user->id`? In the posted code, you define `$UserId` but are then using `$user->id` in the code. And in the last example in the end, you're using `$UserId`?

Comment: Have you checked what the generated query actually looks like? You can use the query helper `$this->db->last_query()` to https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution but not sure how accurate

```
$this->db->where(["Sender" => $user->Id,"Receiver"=>$Receiver]);
$this->db->or_group_start()->where(["Sender" => $Receiver,"Receiver"=>$user->Id])->group_end();
$this->db->order_by("Id DESC");
$sohbetciler = $this->db->get("chatizin")->result();
```